# Key chord for org refresh buffer?

Tags: org-mode, buffers

Due to my Ubuntu 21.04 Wayland being flaky (I suspect), I can't always get the org menu to drop down properly, and I like to do a "Refresh setup current buffer" often. How could I do this with a key chord? Help/Apropos doesn't reveal any likely candidates.

Comment: `C-c C-c` on any keyword line `#+....:` will do that.

Comment: Is the menu broken-ness [like this?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/61240/5223)

Answer (score 1):

You could restart org-mode with `M-x org-mode-restart` and bind it to a key.

Comment: ... which is exactly what `C-c C-c` does on a keyword line.

Comment: Yes, however `M-x org-mode-restart` is like `C-c C-c` on **every** single #+... line. It's handy when you have several #+... lines in your document since you don't have to find the specific line causing the problem, if a #+.. is the problem at all, which might not be the case.

Comment: You can do `C-c C-c` on *any* keyword line, not just the one that caused a problem. You can even add one `#+FOO: bar` right where you are, do `C-c C-c`  and delete it afterwards.

Comment: You can certainly do that. My point was simply that IMHO it's easier to restart org-mode than doing `C-c C-c` on every line, especially if you have several keyword lines in a file.

Comment: No, no, no: you only do it *ONCE* on *ANY* keyword line: it *runs* `org-mode-restart` just as if you had done `M-x org-mode-restart` or whether you bind `org-mode-restart` to some (other) key and use that. The point is that I don't have to remember yet another obscure used-defined key binding: I (almost) *always* have a keyword line that I can use `C-c C-c` on (and I can do `M-x org-mode-restart` on those rare occasions that there isn't one (or I can add one as pointed out before).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification NickD, you're absolutely right. I erroneously thought `C-c C-c` just reloads the option of the #+ line you're on, but that is not the case. Thanks for your comments, I learned something new again! :)